# Android -- Cannot get the videos streaming from my server

Tags: android, android-intent, video-streaming

I am using the following code to stream the videos from my server on android phone:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(videoUrl)); // When I hit this URL in web browser on my PC, it works
startActivity(i);
```

When I run the code, it asks me to select a player. When I select a player, that player opens up and then nothing happens. I've even tried waiting for minutes, but the video never starts.

My question is, is it really as simple to just put the video on my webserver and on android run the above code to get that video streaming?

Do I need to make any changes on my server? Can anyone please help me with this? I cannot figure out if the problem is with my sever or client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the problem of VLC player that I was using on my Android Phone for testing. I downloaded the MX Player and tried it with that. Everything is working fine now :-)

That means not every video player on Google Play is mature enough to take a URL and start streaming the video. For that you need a good video player that supports this feature.